# Armor/weapon bin slots

Tags: monster-hunter-world

Since I am planning on acquiring every weapon (maxed out variations, not the low level ones) as well as all the high rank armors, I was wondering if there is a cap on how many weapons/armors I can have. At the blacksmith, there are only like 4 pages shown. These 4 pages can pretty easily be filled, even more with new monster coming along.

So my question is, is it possible to acquire every weapon/armor in the game and store them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no limit on box sizes, much like your item/material box, it will expand on its own when you fill up the second to last page(as in, fill up page 3 will get you page 5). Below is a screenshot of my gear box filled to page 4, with page 5 being automatically created.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There **is** a hard cap of 1,000 total equipments-and that only counts *equipments* as in armors, weapons and charms. However, the number of pages in the *shown* list of equipments is irrelevant. However, this number can be seen only in very specific situations, such as when appraising Kulve Taroth weapons.

With Iceborne, this limit is expanded to 2,500 total equipments as you reach Master Rank. This expanded limit can be confirmed when you are appraising Safi'jiiva weapons, as shown below. (The numbers are shown besides the investigation points; forgive the Korean language.)
[image: Appraisement of Safi'jiiva weapons from the alchemist.]